# How to use ExposedDropdownMenu to create a multi-steps form?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to disabled textFields to force my users to complete a form in a certain order.
I have created a form composed of 4 `ExposedDropdownMenuBox` and their `TextField`s, and I added a `FocusManager` to move from one input to the `Next` when a value is selected.

I want to find a way to force to make "Choice A -> ... -> Choice D" in that order by disabling the inputs when the previous inputs aren't completed.
For example, I don't want to allow Choice B if Choice A hasn't been selected.

So, based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary.html#ExposedDropdownMenuBox(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)), this is my current code :
([I also created a gist here](https://gist.github.com/cyril-tl/d867ace2c62cd8835d59d908fdbc231d))

```
    @Composable
fun TransferDestination() {
    val optionsA = listOf("-", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
    val optionsB = listOf("-", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4")
    val optionsC = listOf("-", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4",)
    val optionsD = listOf("-", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4",)
    var selectedA by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedB by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedC by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedD by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }

    var expanded0 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded1 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded3 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Column() {
InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice A",
                    isEnabled = true,
                    expanded = expanded0,
                    list = optionsA,
                    value = selectedA,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded0 = !expanded0
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedA = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                           focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded1 = !expanded1
                        }
                    }
                )
InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice B",
                    isEnabled = true,
                    expanded = expanded1,
                    list = optionsB,
                    value = selectedB,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded1 = !expanded1
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedB = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded2 = !expanded2
                        }
                    }
                )

// and same with C and D

}
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun InputSelect(
    label: String = "Label",
    isEnabled: Boolean,
    expanded: Boolean,
    list: List<String>,
    value: String,
    onExpandedChange: () -> Unit,
    onSelect: (str: String) -> Unit
) {
    // We want to react on tap/press on TextField to show menu
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            println("onExpandedChange: label? $label; isEnabled? $isEnabled")
            if (isEnabled) {
                onExpandedChange()
            }
        },
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field for correctness.
            modifier = Modifier
                .menuAnchor()
                .padding(4.dp),
//            enabled = isEnabled,
            enabled = isEnabled,
            readOnly = true,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(label) },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                onExpandedChange()
            },
        ) {
            list.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                    onClick = {
//                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
//                        expanded = false
                        onSelect(selectionOption)
                        onExpandedChange()
                        println("select + change expand")
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how I can make this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that dropdown didn't show because the parameter "`isEnabled`" isn't recompose correctly at the time I need it in `onExpandedChange` , for some reason.

So I encapsulated the `ExposedDropdownMenu` with a condition

```
 if (isEnabled) {
        ExposedDropdownMenu( ... )
 }
```

I also changed a little the solution from @Thracian with the step variable :

```
var step by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

InputSelect(
    label = "Choice A",
    isEnabled = true,
    expanded = expanded0,
    list = optionsA,
    value = selectedA,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded0 = !expanded0
    },
    onSelect = {
        selectedA = it
        expanded0 = false
        if (it != "-") {
            step = 1
            expanded1 = true
            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
        } else {
            step = 0
        }
    }
)

InputSelect(
    label = "Choice B",
    isEnabled = step >= 1,
    expanded = expanded1,
    list = optionsB,
    value = selectedB,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded1 = !expanded1
    },
    onSelect = {
        selectedB = it
        expanded1 = false
        if (it != "-") {
            step = 2
            expanded1 = true
            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
        } else {
            step = 1 // return to this step if C or D were selected
        }
    }
)

InputSelect(
    label = "Choice C",
    isEnabled = step >= 2,
    expanded = expanded2,
    list = optionsC,
    value = selectedC,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded2 = !expanded2
    },
    onSelect = {
        selectedC = it
        expanded2 = false
        if (it != "-") {
            step = 3
            expanded3 = true
            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
        } else {
            step = 2
        }
    }
)

InputSelect(
    label = "Choice D",
    isEnabled = step == 3,
    expanded = expanded3,
    list = optionsD,
    value = selectedD,
    onExpandedChange = {
        expanded3 = !expanded3
    },
    onSelect = {
        selectedD = it
        expanded3 = false
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding these flags

```
var completedA by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var completedB by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var completedC by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

then updating it to true on select and setting the isEnabled parameter of the next one as the previous flag.

Full code:

```
@Composable
fun TransferDestination() {
    val optionsA = listOf("-", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
    val optionsB = listOf("-", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4")
    val optionsC = listOf("-", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4",)
    val optionsD = listOf("-", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4",)
    var selectedA by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedB by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedC by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }
    var selectedD by remember { mutableStateOf("-") }

    var expanded0 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded1 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var expanded3 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var completedA by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var completedB by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var completedC by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    // IME handler
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    val columnModifier = Modifier
        .width(250.dp)
        .padding(end = 8.dp)

    val cornerRadius = 50
    val firstButtonShape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStartPercent = cornerRadius,
        topEndPercent = 0,
        bottomStartPercent = cornerRadius,
        bottomEndPercent = 0
    )
    val lastButtonShape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStartPercent = 0,
        topEndPercent = cornerRadius,
        bottomStartPercent = 0,
        bottomEndPercent = cornerRadius
    )
    var selectedBatB by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val colorSelected = Color(0xFF3F6CB4)
    val colorUnselected = Color(0x803F6CB4)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = "$expanded0, $selectedA, ${selectedA != "-"}")
        Text(text = "$expanded1, $selectedB, ${selectedB != "-"}")
        Text(text = "$expanded2, $selectedC, ${selectedC != "-"}")
        Text(text = "$expanded3, $selectedD, ${selectedD != "-"}")


        val centerHorizon = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        ) {
            Column(modifier = columnModifier.weight(1f), horizontalAlignment = centerHorizon) {
                InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice A",
                    isEnabled = true,
                    expanded = expanded0,
                    list = optionsA,
                    value = selectedA,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded0 = !expanded0
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedA = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                            completedA = true
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded1 = !expanded1

                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            Column(modifier = columnModifier.weight(1f), horizontalAlignment = centerHorizon) {
                InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice B",
                    isEnabled = completedA,
                    expanded = expanded1,
                    list = optionsB,
                    value = selectedB,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded1 = !expanded1
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedB = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                            completedB = true
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded2 = !expanded2
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
        ) {
            Column(modifier = columnModifier.weight(1f), horizontalAlignment = centerHorizon) {
                InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice C",
                    isEnabled = completedB,
                    expanded = expanded2,
                    list = optionsC,
                    value = selectedC,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded2 = !expanded2
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedC = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded3 = !expanded3
                            completedC = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            Column(modifier = columnModifier.weight(1f), horizontalAlignment = centerHorizon) {
                InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice D",
                    isEnabled = completedC,
                    expanded = expanded3,
                    list = optionsD,
                    value = selectedD,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded3 = !expanded3
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedD = it
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected : I can't open dropDowns different than "Choice A", the text fields will be enabled in theory but when I click on it, the line             "println("onExpandedChange: label? $label; isEnabled? $isEnabled")"
 will alaways print "I/System.out: onExpandedChange: label? Choice B; isEnabled? false"

Comment: passing the value "isCompletedXX" to the parameter "enabled" of my InputSelect composable doesn't work, it is always false for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Add a `step` **state** and enable steps in order you want them to be enabled. Increase steps when valid selection is made and decrease it if there is an invalid selection

```
var step by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice A",
                    isEnabled = true,
                    expanded = expanded0,
                    list = optionsA,
                    value = selectedA,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded0 = !expanded0
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedA = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                           focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded1 = !expanded1
                            step++
                        }
                    }
                )
InputSelect(
                    label = "Choice B",
                    isEnabled = step > 0,
                    expanded = expanded1,
                    list = optionsB,
                    value = selectedB,
                    onExpandedChange = {
                        expanded1 = !expanded1
                    },
                    onSelect = {
                        selectedB = it
                        if (it != "-") {
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                            expanded2 = !expanded2
                            step++
                        }
                    }
                )
```

If you want them to be enabled only correct state you can use `=` instead of `>`